# How to use decimal variable

Tags: objective-c, variables, decimal

I am using a For loop to cycle through variables in an array that contain percentages. For each value I run through an equation to give me an average of all the percentages. The only problem is that I am unsure how to change the variable types to accommodate decimals whilst also work in with my equation.

```
// Calculate average of all percentages for specific exercise
long totalNumber = 0;
int temp;
long numberOfObjects = [iterationArray count];
for (NSArray *object in iterationArray) {
    temp = [(NSNumber *)[object objectAtIndex:4] intValue]/100;
    totalNumber = totalNumber + temp;
}
exercisePercentage = (totalNumber/numberOfObjects)*100;

return exercisePercentage;
```

I know that `temp` is the variable that needs to be a decimal. I was considering using an `NSDecimalNumber` but didn't know how to fit in with the rest of the code to return a `long` value.

I've tried with making temp a `double` or `float` but both return 0 on the line `temp = [(NSNumber *)[object objectAtIndex:4] intValue]/100;` despite the fact that `[(NSNumber *)[object objectAtIndex:4] intValue]` is 80.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Division of int with int always returns int, so you need to convert one value into float or double, something like this:

```
// Calculate average of all percentages for specific exercise
double totalNumber = 0.0;
double temp;
long numberOfObjects = [iterationArray count];
for (NSArray *object in iterationArray) {
    temp = [(NSNumber *)[object objectAtIndex:4] intValue]/100.0;
    totalNumber = totalNumber + temp;
}
exercisePercentage = (totalNumber/numberOfObjects)*100.0;

return exercisePercentage;
```

See it's 100.0, now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the type of temp form int to float or double.

```
double temp;
float temp;
```